# Encurtador url C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, return

Estou ajustando um código em c# para um api de encurtador de url para enviar no sms dentro de um aplicativo, está tudo funcionando, porém o api fora do código funciona, mas dentro do código o o return não volta nada, não sou muito experiente em c#, alguém pode me ajudar? Segue o código:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string EncurtadorUrl(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            string urlMigreMe = string.Format("http://tiny-url.info/api/v1/create?url={0}&apikey={APIKEY}chave_aqui&provider=bit_ly");

            var client = new WebClient();
            string response = client.DownloadString(urlMigreMe);

            return response;
        }
        catch 

        {
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: Você está substituindo esse {APIKEY} pela chave da API em algum lugar antes de fazer a requisição?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uso errado ou indevido do método [format da class String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) que está errado: quando se quer formatar uma **string**, colocasse a numeração de **0** até a **quantidade** de paramento que precisa, no caso são dois, então, `{0}` e `{1}`

***Veja edição do código:***

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string EncurtadorUrl(string url)
    {
        try
        {                
            string urlMigreMe = string.Format("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url={0}", url);

            var client = new WebClient();

            string response = client.DownloadString(urlMigreMe);

            client.Dispose();

            return response;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static string EncurtadorUrl(Uri url)
    {
        return EncurtadorUrl(url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

***Maneira de usar:***

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          string url = Helpers.EncurtadorUrl(new Uri("http://www.uol.com.br"));
          //dado contido na variavel url coloque no navegador vai abrir a pagina
     }
}
```

[Método String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Mas e o  
{
            return "";
        } é esse resultado que eu preciso! E ele não me gera nenhum resultado.

Comment: Pera um pouco, se ele não retorna um dado, porque está acontecendo um erro: debug o erro para consertar alguma coisa no código! entendeu, me diz qual é o erro que está acontecendo? que eu edito e te ajudo a visualizar isso. Se der erro, pode ter mecanismo para solucionar o problema!

Comment: Então eu preciso que o response me retorne a url encurtada, ele não apresenta erro mas também fica vazio, sem nenhum dado.

Comment: Acabei de realizar os testes e crie um apiKey e funcionou! você colocou ali a sua ApiKey?

Comment: Sim, essa api faz parte do envio de sms de um app, no caso ela encurta um link para visualizar um pdf, não consigo encontrar o erro, mas sei que é no api, porque mesmo fazendo um teste e colocando algum valor no return " " ele me mostra no sms, mas da forma que eu pretendo ele não mostra nada, fica vazio.

Comment: Você gostaria de usar outro provider de geração de url curtas?

Comment: Na realidade eu estou usando esse porque é o único que sei em C#, pode ser esse o problema?

Comment: @AugustoFelipe a url estava errada dá uma olhada agora ele vai gerar a url corretamente e você coloque o resultado no seu navegador ele vai carregar a pagina!

Comment: Fiz uma alteração no código @AugustoFelipe utilize ele para seus testes!

Comment: Obrigado! Valeu mesmo, deu certo por aqui! :)

Answer (score 2):

O código está funcionando perfeitamente. Apenas certifique de passar uma URL válida, como por exemplo:

```
        string urlMigreMe = string.Format("http://tiny-url.info/api/v1/create?url=http://google.com&apikey=APIKEYAQUI&provider=bit_ly");

        var client = new WebClient();
        string response = client.DownloadString(urlMigreMe);
```

Neste exemplo utilizando a url do google, o valor obtido de retorno foi:

> http://tw.gs/4Yudb2

#### Edição

Para passar a url por parâmetro, faça dessa forma:

```
string urlMigreMe = string.Format("http://tiny-url.info/api/v1/create?url=
                                   {0}&apikey={APIKEY}&provider=bit_ly", URL AQUI);
```

Comment: Então eu quero que ele encurte uma url variável que é um link com a id de um gerador de pdf, cada vez é gerado uma url diferente, olha como está:

Comment: Helpers.EncurtadorUrl(string.Format("http://www.agafcomunicacao.com.br/vectradental/GerarPdf/Index?exame={0}", exame.Id));
                new EnvioSms(ParametroGeralService).EnviaSMSExemplo("", "", paciente, string.Format("Vectra- Seu Dentista solicitou o exame {1} - Ligue {0} para agendar.", odontomedica, url), "");
                HttpResponseMessage responseNaoExiste = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Message = "Exame Cadastrado!" });
                return Task.FromResult(responseNaoExiste);

Comment: @AugustoFelipe Não entendi. As URL's são diferentes?

Comment: isso, a aplicação gera sempre que solicitado uma url diferente em agafcomunicacao.com.br/‌​vectradental/GerarPd‌​f/Index?exame={0}, no caso apenas em {0} que é o id do pdf que é diferente para cada solicitação.

Comment: @AugustoFelipe Então. Você tem que ter certeza que está passando uma url válida para a API. Note que em seu código você está utilizando `...create?url={0}`, mas em nenhum momento altera o `{0}` pelo valor real da url

Comment: É possível eu fazer essa chamada para um url variável em C#, desculpe mas não tenho tanto conhecimento em C#.

Comment: @AugustoFelipe Veja a edição. Você só precisa passar o valor da URL com uma **vírgula** no `string.Format()`